# How can I run jdbc:initialize-database using condition?

Tags: xml, database, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I'm using this code to init my database

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="ALL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/dropDDL.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/createDDL.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Here the code is executed when I read the xml file, but I would like to run this code using a condition !!
any suggestions?

Comment: 1) What is the condition? 2) Are you willing to move to Java config instead of xml?

Comment: for exemple:If(databaseIsEmpty)
{//then execute the code}
else{
//nothing
}

Comment: Do mean that you don't want to run `sql/dropDDL.sql` and `sql/createDDL.sql`, but the datasource should always be present?

Comment: no I would like to run sql/dropDDL.sql and sql/createDDL.sql if database is empty

Comment: I see. And how do you know if the database is empty?

Comment: I check a variable using datasource and connection ....